# Proof of the Construction of a wedge of circles

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

The following is the proof of the construction of a wedge of circles from Munkres' Topology. I don't understand the final two lines of the proof. So we have that $\pi^{-1}(D)\cap (S^1 \times \alpha)$ is closed in $S^1 \times \alpha$, but how does this imply that $\pi^{-1}(D)$ is closed in $S^1 \times J$. 
The only logic I can see is that a closed set in a subspace is of the form $C \cap S$, where $C$ is a closed set of the original space and $S$ is the subspace, but this does not guarantee that $\pi^{-1}(D)$ must be a closed set in $S^1 \times J$, so how is this conclusion guaranteed?
[image]

Comment: A set in $S\times J$ is closed if its intersection with every $S^1\times\alpha$ is closed. It is because $J$ has the discrete topology, thus $J=\oplus_{\alpha\in J}\{\alpha\}$. The product is then homeomorphic to a topological sum $\oplus_\alpha S^1\times\{\alpha\}$.

Comment: As an exercise I recommend showing that given a space $S$ and a collection of spaces $(X_\alpha)_\alpha$, there is a homeomorphism $\oplus_\alpha S\times X_\alpha \approx S\times\oplus_\alpha X_\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that $J$ has been given the discrete topology, so each of the sets $S^1\times\{\alpha\}$ with $\alpha\in J$ is a clopen (i.e., closed and open) subset of $S^1\times J$. Suppose that $A$ is a subset of $S^1\times J$ with the property that $A\cap(S^1\times\{\alpha\})$ is closed in $S^1\times\{\alpha\}$ for each $\alpha\in J$; we want to show that $A$ is closed in $S^1\times J$. Let $\langle x,\alpha\rangle\in(S^1\times J)\setminus A$; we need to show that $\langle x,\alpha\rangle$ has an open nbhd in $S^1\times J$ that is disjoint from $A$.

Let $U=(S^1\times\{\alpha\})\setminus A$; since $A\cap(S^1\times\{\alpha\})$ is closed in $S^1\times\{\alpha\}$, $U$ must be open in $S^1\times\{\alpha\}$. And $S^1\times\{\alpha\}$ is open in $S^1\times J$, so $U$ is actually open in $S^1\times J$. Clearly $\langle x,\alpha\rangle\in U$ and $U\cap A=\varnothing$, so $U$ is an open nbhd of $\langle x,\alpha\rangle$ disjoint from $A$. And $\langle x,\alpha\rangle$ was an arbitrary point of $(S^1\times J)\setminus A$, so $A$ is indeed closed in $S^1\times J$.

Now take $A$ to be $\pi^{-1}[D]$, and you have the desired result.